# DB Improving schema for room booking problem but with n number of overlaps and weekly availability,

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

It's similar to the room booking issue so I ended up using a similar schema.
as seen in the image, we've got a area which can have multiple slots , 0-Infinity , and area_availability which will be 7 rows / area , each for each day of the week and having a start and end time

now the issue or more like complexity that i've created here is that when someone from a different timezone has to turn off bookings for a an area for a certain day, let's say wednesday , the dayofweek would be 3 and I would easily just remove that day from the area_availability table.

that's if there's no concept of timezone but they exist and if an area has to be off from a timezone -5:30 then it won't just remove the row with `dayofweek` = 3 but instead it'll block times from tuesday post 7.00 pm to wednesday 7.00am in UTC and then it'd behave as expected.

this works right now but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it.

So that it can support both international bookings and querying the next available slot could be made easier to do.

#### Finer details

1. Each booking can be from any point to any point but has to be a min of 1 hour
2. The timestamps stored in the start_time and end_time aren't with timezones
3. There's no timezone data regarding the area at all right now

[image]

Comment: I would definitely use a range type for this, including constraints: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html dayofweek is something that can be extracted from the timestamp, no need to store that again

Comment: @FrankHeikens so a range for just the timestamps? what difference does it make? 
Also, at given time there's only 7 rows if I change it to ranges of datetime, then do you want me to add a check that adds the current day as offset ? or did you have something else in mind?